# Problem when executing a script with onblur

Tags: javascript

I take the liberty of posting this topic because I find myself in a situation that I can't explain.

I created a stopwatch that allows to record the time spent when clicking on stop (it also sends the client id, the comment left by the employee, the creation date and the person who did the work).

For security reasons, I blocked the submit button once the user has clicked once. I also offer the possibility to save a task and resume it later. And here, while the html code of the stopwatch is identical, it doesn't work anymore. Indeed, you can click twice before it freezes (and not once as before).

Here is what the button looks like when you click :
[image]

Here is the corresponding JavaSript code :

```
function verifComm(text){
console.log('verifComm');
    if(text.value.length < 5){
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var n = 1;
        btnSend = document.getElementById("envoi");
        btnSave = document.getElementById("sauv");
        btnSend.addEventListener('click', function desactiverEnvoiBouton(){
            document.getElementById('envoi').value='Envoi en cours...';
            document.getElementById('envoi').style.opacity = "0.5";
            if(n>1){
                document.getElementById('envoi').disabled=true;
            }
            n = n+1;
            console.log('Clic sur envoi');
        });
        btnSave.addEventListener('click', function desactiverSauvegardeBouton(){
            document.getElementById('sauv').value='Sauvegarde en cours...';
            document.getElementById('sauv').style.opacity = "0.5";
            if(n>1){
                document.getElementById('sauv').disabled=true;
            }
            n = n+1;
        });
    return true;
    }
}

// Vérification avant envoi du formulaire
function verifForm(f){
    var CommOk = verifComm(f.commentaireEnregistre);
    var CommSaveOk = verifComm(f.commentaireSauvegarde);
    if( (CommOk) || (CommSaveOk)){
    return true;
    }
    else{
        alert("Veuillez commenter la tâche (minimum 5 caractères)");
        return false;
    }
}
```

And this is what the code of the page looks like: (I made a screenshot because I can't share my code, he doesn't want to publish the topic otherwise)
[image]

If you need more code or explanations, don't hesitate to let me know.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

I look forward to hearing from you,

Damien

Comment: In order to reproduce the issue you need to share the code. No one is going to write it by hand from the screenshot you shared.

Comment: You need to make [mre] like everyone else, And by posting picture of code you already shared it.  Just not in helping way to make it easy for us to help you... Make a snippet by pressing `<>` in editor to reproduce the issue. Like everyone else... Pictures of code are big no-no here on SO.